# How can I configure Wi-Fi credentials for an access point that is not in range?

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

Is it possible to connect to a Wi-Fi network that is not in range (and hence not listed on the list of Wi-Fi networks nearby), so that when it is it automatically connects?

I cannot select the Wi-Fi network currently because it is not listed, but I want to save the credentials for the network before I bring the device within range.

Is this possible with NetworkManager?

Comment: @Fabian i believe I have

Comment: What do you mean?  Of course if it's not in range you cannot connect pretty much be definition of "not in range".  I guess you want to configure?  If so then it's the same as if it is in range, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you running `Ubuntu` - if not the reference to `NetworkManager` is spurious. The answer to your question is totally different for `Raspbian`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it as long as you know the SSID and the credentials.

A more detailed process is listed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md), but the basics are to create/modify `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` with contents similar to :

```
network={
    ssid="yourSSID"
    psk="networkpassword"
}
```